# How is the central limit useful in this cases

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Wikipedia's article reads:

> Normal distributions are important in statistics and are often used in the natural and social sciences to represent real-valued random variables whose distributions are not known.[2][3] Their importance is partly due to the central limit theorem. It states that, under some conditions, the average of many samples (observations) of a random variable with finite mean and variance is itself a random variable—whose distribution converges to a normal distribution as the number of samples increases. Therefore, physical quantities that are expected to be the sum of many independent processes, such as measurement errors, often have distributions that are nearly normal.

I interpret this part:

> It states that, under some conditions, the average of many samples (observations) of a random variable with finite mean and variance is itself a random variable—whose distribution converges to a normal distribution as the number of samples increases.

So withdrawing from the bag of observations and averaging every $n$ observations. Is this correct ?

What if it involves withdrawing from many different bags $n$ times, and averaging ?

I am assuming the same holds there.

### Main Question

But how is this useful in practice, where we cant do that ?  No one does any averaging in practice.

Can you explain it in simple terms, rather that with a lot of formulas?

Comment: "No one does any averaging in practice" seems a sweeping statement.  The normal approximation can also work for sums.

Comment: Why is a sweeping statement ? @Henry

Comment: As Henry says: it works for averages, but also for sums. You maybe noticed that Wikipedia even swiches back and forth between sums and avaragers. Now in the case of sums we can sort-of-say 'Nature does the adding for us'. That is to say: central limit theorem applies to situations that are the effect of adding many many different small indepedent effects that we don't know/understand and hence may model as random. This is what the sentence "Therefore, physical quantities that are expected to be the sum of many independent processes often have distributions that are nearly normal." tries to say

Comment: Wikipedia talks about measurement error, but a famous example of something that is distributed normally is human height. You might argue that this is an example of what we are talking about: height results as the 'sum' of many independent contributions by different genes, available nutrition through life etc

Comment: @Vincent Height is not normally distributed...if you are talking about male height or female height, then yes. In fact, if any one variable accounts for a large part of the variability, then you probably won't have normality.

Comment: @Andrew yes good point! Unfonately too late to edit my comment

Comment: That's exactly my point though, if you collapse vincent + andrew, you get why the question i.e I see no guarantee that they will be normally distributed (for example, in height.) As for the sum, yes that's clear, but I don't think _sweeping statement_ is a friendly term here. You can just say: it works for sums as well. Short enough ! @Vincent